# Replace for loop in pyspark group of dataset

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, cluster-computing, databricks

I have dataframe which has different2 schema, So to apply the schema on each group of dataset I am using for loop like:

```py
        disDF = orgDF.distinct('col1','col2').collect()
        for row in disDF:
          newdf = orgDF.filter(orgDF.col1=row.col1).filter(orgDF.col2=row.col2)
          #Now applyting the schema on newdf and then saving this into delta table
```

Now I want to remove the for loop with any other efficient approach which process parallelly.
Because for loop run on master node only which is not working effectively.

THanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried joining the two dataframes?

Comment: It seems you save all the data from orgDF to your delta table in batches. Maybe you can apply your schema on the whole orgDF, then order by ('col1','col2') and then save the whole table?

Comment: Actually whole data is coming as json string of a column and have to explode that column and will applying the schema. But issue with data is that it has different version in a single dataframe which I am grouping then for each group is applying schema.